Vite reloads page instead of HMR in vanilla JS project
I'm facing an issue with vite, somehow i initialize a new Umbraco project with Vite as a bundler.
Even when im adding hmr: true, or once im including the files that vite should watch, vite still reloads the page instead of using hmr on save of a file.
Any ideas why?

it's hard to tell without a minimum reproducible example, maybe you change dependencies of index.html or main.js, in that case the whole page reloading makes sense

Its a clean install. Lets say im adding a tailwind class, page reloads, even on .js file where i tried to use if (import.meta.hot) {
import.meta.hot.accept();
}
Hmr working for an instance of a second, and then the page still reloads once im saving the file.
